# xcb: expose event for every screen refresh

Tags: c++, c, xcb

I'm using the xcb library. I would like to receive an expose event, or something similar, every time the screen is refreshed. Basically I want screen sync (vsync). Is this possible to do in xcb?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to do this, but I would guess that the PRESENT extension makes something like this possible. From a quick look at https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/presentproto/tree/presentproto.txt, this part of the introduction caught my eye:

> synchronizing
> with the display refresh

However, I do not know any details. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I have just found that if I add the xcb file descriptor to epoll (with a timeout of -1, i.e. block indefinitely until an event comes in), epoll reports it ready every 16 ms (60 FPS).

The readiness doesn't seem to come with any `XCB_` event...`xcb_poll_for_event` just returns null.

This behaviour was completely unexpected and I can't find any documentation as to why this is happening, but it is basically giving me vsync synchronised behaviour I am after (whilst still being able to wait on other file descriptors).

Note that I have to call `eglSwapBuffers` to get this readiness behaviour.